# Node.js spawn child process best practice

Tags: node.js, module, mocha.js, child-process

I need to spawn a mocha process. It can be installed either locally, or globally, I don't know in advance.

This works only if mocha is installed globally:

```
require("child_process").spawn("mocha", argv._, {
    stdio: 'inherit'
});
```

Is there a way to spawn the process so it will work in both cases?

Comment: This is probably a good scenario for the new [`peerDependencies`](http://blog.nodejs.org/2013/02/07/peer-dependencies/), which could resolve the "*I don't know in advance*." The feature was released with Node 0.8.19 and NPM 1.2.10.

Comment: You can try to find if mocha is available locally via `module.paths`. If not try to spawn it globally. Otherwise spawn it via local path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js: programmatically setting NODE\_PATH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358994/node-js-programmatically-setting-node-path)