# Node.js: programmatically setting NODE_PATH

Tags: node.js

I would like to load files dynamically in Node.js and this poses a problem that Node looks in `node_modules` of the calling modules instead of looking in the `node_modules` of file being loaded.

The reason I do not want to use `require()` is because these are plugins and they can be included in the main app by simply being concatenating. So using `require()` breaks the plugins. They have to be loaded directly into the main app context, but they have to have access to their local `node_modules` as well.

I use `vm.runInNewContext()` to evaluate the code. But how do I pass `NODE_PATH` to `runInNewContext()`?

Answer (score 35):

To set `NODE_PATH` programmatically, you can run this magic on top of your root node file ([source](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520#gistcomment-1249909)):

```
process.env.NODE_PATH = "your/path";
require("module").Module._initPaths();
```

But keep your eyes peeled when you upgrade your node lest they change how it works.

Comment: If anyone's trying to use NODE_PATH and it's not working, make sure you have this second line with the `_initPaths()` call.

Comment: Thank you @dwelle, it works for me! One note is that you just need to put the code before you require the module which needs a special NODE_PATH.

Comment: Thanks, using the second line with dotenv fixes my problem

Answer (score 1):

Since `vm.runInNewContext()` has no knowledge about your current context, nor is it given its own new "global" context, I assume the following would work:

```
var sb = { process: { env: { NODE_PATH: '/my/path/' }}};
vm.runInNewContext('process.env', sb);
// return: { NODE_PATH: '/my/path/' }
```

Unless I'm missing something. If I am could you explain in more detail?