# are we able to import and export functions in cypress.io?

Tags: function, testing, import, export, cypress

there are few functions I want to use across the testing integrations in `cypress.io` is there a way to export / import the functions so I don't have to copy and paste the functions into each `integration`?

Thanks in advance for any advice

Comment: you can use commonJS (`require()`) or es6 `import` inside your spec files

Comment: @Dwelle weird maybe I didn't set it up correctly because it didn't work.  so I got confused.  Let me try again

Comment: @Dwelle it does work, thx thx.  but do you know if there is anyway I can make it always direct to a root directory? if I have a few directories I have to do something like `../.../../../something.js` unlike how `fixtures` will find `fixtures` folder as it's root

Comment: for normal node projects I'm using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33976627/927631) but not sure you'll be able to use it in cypress

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can do it as you would do it in usual js code.

myFunction.js

```
export function funcName(param) {
  return "Cypress is "+param;
}
```

myCypressTest.js

```
import { funcName } from "./myFunction.js";
funcName("great");
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful for you.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#

You can define custom cypress commands and use them in your tests. ie cypress.login, cypress.clickHamburger, cypress.doSomethingCrazy

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use `import` in your spec file.

For example, if you want to import a function `add()` from a `Model.js`, you can do something like:

`import Model from '../../Model';
 var model = new Model();`

And call `model.add()` from your `expect`.

Comment: getting following error using that way of import: 
ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'