# How to change NODE_PATH dynamically?

Tags: node.js, path, node-modules

In my mocha tests I want to require files from the `./lib` folder without specifying relative path to a required file. Instead of `require('../../../lib/folder/file')` I want to `require('folder/file')`

I was able to achieve this with `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "NODE_ENV=test NODE_PATH=./test:./lib mocha test/**/*_spec.js"
}
```

Before modifying `package.json` I tried to change `NODE_PATH` in my `test_helper.js` like this

```
// test/test_helper.js

const path = require('path');

process.env.NODE_PATH = `${process.env.NODE_PATH}:${path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'lib')}`;
```

and in my test file

```
// test/folder/file_test.js

require('test_helper');
console.log(process.env.NODE_PATH);  // outputs ./test:/project-path/lib

const module = require('folder/file');

describe('test', function() {});
```

And when I run `npm test` it fails with

```
Error: Cannot find module 'folder/file'
```

What am I doing wrong with configuring `NODE_PATH` dynamically?

Comment: Can [module.createRequireFromPath(filename)](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_createrequirefrompath_filename) be of any help in your situation?

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33976627/454780